# Multi Lookup Dates Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I working on where i lookup a row and then that column.
I succeeded in it , but i am not able to lookup dates before 10th of the month ie. single digits

```
Sub PerformLookups()
Dim firstLookupValue As String
Dim secondLookupValue As String
Dim secondLookupValuePartial As String
Dim firstLookupRange As Range
Dim secondLookupRange As Range
Dim outputCell As Range
Dim outputCell2 As Range


firstLookupValue = "1606"
secondLookupValue = "25-Feb-2023"
secondLookupValuePartial = Format(dateValue(secondLookupValue), "dd-mmm")
MsgBox secondLookupValuePartial

Set firstLookupRange = Sheets("Actiph").Rows(2)


Set outputCell = firstLookupRange.Find(What:=firstLookupValue, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
MsgBox outputCell


If Not outputCell Is Nothing Then

    Set secondLookupRange = outputCell.EntireColumn
    
    Set outputCell2 = secondLookupRange.Find(What:=secondLookupValuePartial, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    MsgBox outputCell2
    
End If
```

The secondlookupValue is in "dd-mmm-yyyy" format and the secondlookupRange is in "dd-mmm" format.

How can change the format to consider single digit dates also

Comment: Is the column where you try finding `secondLookupValue` formatted `As Date`? If so, Excel keeps that cells as numeric values. So you should declare it `As Date` and give to it a value using `secondLookupValue = DateValue("25-Feb-2023")`. Then, use `....Find(What:=CLng(secondLookupValue), ...` VBA does not search as you do it visually, looking to the format. It searches to `Find` the numeric value of the cell: 44982 for "25-Feb-2023"...